# Asking about tuning a TV

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there any site on Stack Exchange where I can ask about tuning a TV?

I was looking through the Stack Exchange sites and really don't know where I should post this.

I was forwarded on to here from the SE site "Movies & TV" - any recommendations for where I can post this or should I go outside of SE?

Comment: Geez, I haven't tuned a TV since I was a kid with a set that had actual, physical dials and rabbit ears. Given that, you describe in a little more detail what you mean by "tuning" a TV?

Comment: @DanBron Sure no problem - I just wanted to make sure that this was the right place before I started going into more detail. Essentially the TV has FreeView - called FreeSat, which we've tried tuning with a normal antennae which doesn't pick up any channels. This leads me to believe that it needs a satellite connection just to pick up the Freeview channels. I'll post back later the exact spec and setup we have

Comment: @Cai that's exactly what I thought. Will report back what I do, assuming that it fixes it

Comment: Katana24: `I will report back...` Good luck with your issue! but please don't continue your troubleshooting/resolution here. I'm afraid we don't currently have a site that hosts these subjects, but meta.stackexchange is *not* the place to continue trouble-shooting and resolving this issue. Thanks.

Comment: @RobertCartaino Ok np - I'll delete the question. Thanks

Comment: That's not necessary. Asking if such a site exists is perfectly on topic here.

Answer (score 4):

No. There is not a Stack Exchange for this - it is a very specific requirement you have, and while the general process is very straightforward, the specifics vary depending on the hardware and firmware you have.